# alt text for script tag in html body

Tags: javascript, html

I embed a GitHub gist on my webpage using the script tag as follows

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/uname/id.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to provide alt text in case the gist doesn't load? I tried the `alt` attribute within the script tag but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Script tags are none visual, so how exactly do you envisage alt working?.

Comment: Ideally, if the gist doesn't show up, it would be nice to show alt text in that space on the screen. Does that make sense?
Something like `try:<script ../> except: <p>alt text</p>`

Comment: Check https://rawgit.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at how gist's are embedded they use `document.write`.

And then inside there it will create some markup, so what we could do is check to see if the markup has been created after waiting a while, if no gist has been loaded then they won't be any markup with a class of `.gist`.

Below is a working example.
if you run the snippet it should fail after 5 seconds and show a message, if you then replace `4577639.js_bad` with just `4577639.js` it will then hopefully work and failed to load message should not appear.

ps. Not sure if this is the official way of falling back, but it seems to work ok.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  if (!document.querySelector(".gist")) {
    document.querySelector("#failed-to-load").
      style.display = "block";
  }
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="failed-to-load" style="display:none">
Failed to load Gist
</div>
<script src="https://gist.github.com/claudemamo/4577639.js_bad"></script>
```

Comment: This looks great, thanks! I have multiple gists on the page, I will just look up the ids of the `div` tags that the script creates instead of `.gist`. That should work.